# How to print user inputs from python on a regular printer through an HTML Template?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to design a software to print bank checks using regular printer. I wrote a python script with a GUI which takes user inputs and saves it on database, and can display it back again from within the app. I also designed a HTML file with the exact coordinates of my bank check. I am totally lost as to how i can link these two, so i can print the user inputs to the bank check.

[image: The Input Fields]

Here's the code of the script:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import mysql.connector

# MySQL Connection

dbms = mysql.connector.connect( host='127.0.0.1', 
                                user='root', 
                                password='password', 
                                database='app')

myCursor = dbms.cursor()

# Add some color to the window
sg.theme('Default1')
sg.set_options(font='Courier 16')

RecordsData = []
myCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM app.inputs")
for i in myCursor:
    RecordsData.append(list(i))
headersRecords = ['pay_to', 'amount_words', 'amount', 'address', 'purpose', 'drawer', 'issue_date', 'company']

# Functions to update new data on the display tables on refreshing

def refresh_records():
    dbms2 = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                                    user="root",
                                    password="password",
                                    database="app")

    myCursor2 = dbms2.cursor()
    data = []
    myCursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM app.inputs;")
    for j in myCursor2:
        data.append(list(j))
    window1['-table1-'].Update(values=data)
    sg.popup("Records Updated!")

# Clearing from functions

def clear_records():
    for key in values:
        window1['pay_to'].update('')
        window1['amount_words'].update('')
        window1['amount'].update('')
        window1['address'].update('')
        window1['purpose'].update('')
        window1['drawer'].update('')
        window1['issue_date'].update('')
        window1['company'].update('')

    return None

# Submitting functions

def submit_records():
    pay_to = values['pay_to']
    if pay_to == '':
        sg.popup_error('Missing Pay_to')
    amount_words = values['amount_words']
    if amount_words == '':
        sg.popup_error('Missing amount in words')
    amount = values['amount']
    if amount == '':
        sg.popup_error('Missing amount')
    address = values['address']
    if address == '':
        sg.popup_error('Missing address')
    purpose = values['purpose']
    if purpose == '':
        sg.popup_error('Missing purpose')
    drawer = values['drawer']
    if drawer == '':
        sg.popup_error('Missing drawer')
    issue_date = values['issue_date']
    if issue_date == '':
        sg.popup_error('Missing issue_date')
    company = values['company']
    if company == '':
        sg.popup_error('Missing company')
    else:
        try:
            command = myCursor.execute("""INSERT INTO app.inputs (pay_to, amount_words, amount, address, purpose, drawer, issue_date, company) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(pay_to, amount_words, amount, address, purpose, drawer, issue_date, company))
            print(command)
            myCursor.execute(command)
            dbms.commit()
            choice = sg.popup_ok_cancel("Please confirm entry")
            if choice == 'OK':
                clear_records()
                sg.popup_quick('records entered')
            else:
                sg.popup_ok('Edit Entry')
        except:
            sg.popup('Please check your inputs. Something is wrong!')

# GUI Layout

recordsTable_layout = [
    [sg.T('RECORDS')],
    [sg.Table(headings=headersRecords, values=RecordsData, display_row_numbers=True, enable_events=True,
            justification='center', key='-table1-')],
    [sg.Button("Refresh Records", key='-refreshR-', expand_x=True)],
    [sg.Button("Exit", expand_x=True)]
]

RecordsForm_layout = [
    [sg.T('Records File')],
    [sg.T('pay_to'), sg.Push(), sg.I(size=(30, 5), key='pay_to')],
    [sg.T('amount_words'), sg.Push(), sg.I(size=(30, 5), key='amount_words')],
    [sg.T('amount'), sg.Push(), sg.I(size=(30, 5), key='amount')],
    [sg.T('address'), sg.Push(), sg.I(size=(30, 5), key='address')],
    [sg.T('purpose'), sg.Push(), sg.I(size=(30, 5), key='purpose')],
    [sg.T('drawer'), sg.Push(), sg.I(size=(30, 5), key='drawer')],
    [sg.T('issue_date'), sg.Push(), sg.I(size=(30, 5), key='issue_date')],
    [sg.T('company'), sg.Push(), sg.Combo(size=(30, 5), values=['Medivet', 'Agri-Master'], key='company')],
    [sg.Button('Submit', key='-submit-', expand_x=True), sg.Button('Clear', key='-clear-', expand_x=True), sg.Button('Exit', key='-exit-', expand_x=True)]
]

main_layout = [
    [sg.Button('View RECORDS', key='-viewR-')],
    [sg.Button('Enter RECORDS', key='-enterR-')],
    [sg.Button('Exit', key='-exit-')]
]
window= sg.Window("Medivet Check", main_layout)

# MAIN

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED or '-exit-'):
        break
    if event == '-viewR-':
        window1 = sg.Window("", recordsTable_layout)
        event, values = window1.read()
        if event == 'Exit':
            window1.close()
        if event == '-refreshR-':
            refresh_records()
    if event == '-enterR-':
        window1 = sg.Window("Records Form", RecordsForm_layout)
        event, values = window1.read()
        if event == '-submit-':
            submit_records()
        if event == '-clear-':
            clear_records()
        if event == '-exit-':
            window1.close()

window.close()
```

And here's how it looks:

Now, this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="check">
  <div class="border">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="one">
        <div class="title">
          
          
          <div class="number">DATE:| 15 | 12 | 2022|</div>

         <table class="add">
          <td class="lines"><input type="text" PLACEHOLDER="PAY" name="address" size="13"></td>
          <tr>
          <td class="amountwords"><input type="text" PLACEHOLDER="AMOUNT IN WORDS" name="citystate" size="13"></td>
          <tr>
      </table>  
          
          <table class="following">
              <tr>
              <tr><td class="empty line"><input type="text" name="reason" placeholder="KHR" size="13"></td>
          </table>
          <table class="cookie">
            <td class="half"><input type="text"Placeholder="Address again" name="drawdress" size="13"></td>
            <tr>
            <td class="half"><input type="text"Placeholder="REASON" name="reason" size="13"></td>
          </table>
  
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Can someone please help? I've looked online a lot. Some used ODF, some used notepad, some HTML.. but no clear explainations.. How do solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking look at some *templating system*, for example [Jinja2](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/), you just need to mark places which will then be filled during rendering, consider following simple example

```
import jinja2
html = "<p>Name</p><i>{{ name }}</i><p>Occupation</p><i>{{ occupation }}</i>"
data = {"name":"Joe","occupation":"developer"}
template = jinja2.Template(html)
rendered = template.render(**data)
print(rendered)
```

gives output

```
<p>Name</p><i>Joe</i><p>Occupation</p><i>developer</i>
```